# List[Nothing] cant be appended to in Scala

Tags: scala

have a var, why its var is because it could be updated during the program intended.

```
var Encountered = List.empty
```

when i try to make it Encountered needs to be added a string, it gives me a `value += is not a member of List[Nothing]`

```
     else{
      Encountered += (Name)

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `familiesEncountered += (familyName)` is not the way to add an element to a list in Scala.

Second, Say the type explicitly:

```
var Encountered: List[String] = List.empty
Encountered =  "elem1" :: Encountered
```

Another way:

```
var encountered: List[String] = Nil
encountered =  "elem1" :: encountered
```

Because if you do:

```
var Encountered = List.empty
Encountered =  "elem1" :: Encountered
```

it won't compile, because if you don't say the type, the type of the list will be `Encountered : List[Nothing]`

Comment: Or `var encountered = List.empty[String]`.

Answer (score 0):

Scala List is an alias for [scala.collection.immutable
List](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html)
 which is immutable, so it doesn't have this method.

`var` is a variable that can be reassigned, but it doesn't make the object it holds mutable.